# fread() does not read the correct values from binary file

Tags: c, integer, fread

I have a binary file containing only integers. I try to read 10 integers with the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


int main(int argc, char **argv){

  int* data=(int*)malloc(10*sizeof(int));

  FILE *fp=fopen("data.bin","rb");
  if(fp==NULL){printf("Error opening the file data.bin\n");}

  size_t w=fread(data,sizeof(int),10,fp);
  if(w!=10){printf("Error reading the data from data.bin\n");}
  fclose(fp);


  printf("%i",data[0]);
}
```

The problem is that the values tha are read are not the expected. For example the first integer is 0, but the printf command prints 86183936. I viewed the file as hex and the bytes are as they should be.

Comment: When you are using `fread()` to read from a file, The data should be written into the file using `fwrite()`.

Comment: "Binary file containing only integers" - not specified enough. Big- or little-endian? How many bytes? Try to create your file using similar code and `fwrite` and compare the create file with the file you already have.

Comment: Are you sure zero in the file is the same size as `int`? Looks like your binary file might only be using a single byte for each integer.

Comment: syntactically your code is right. Its in the way you have written the file that might be the problem. You should've used  `fwrite(data,sizeof(int),10,fp);` like this. And assuming that `sizeof(int)` and endianness is same in both the systems that you are running the fread and fwrite on.

Comment: Show us the first few lines of your file.  Describe the format of the file.

Comment: `0` is the 1st expected integer.  What is the 2nd, 3rd & 4th? (16, 35, 5?)  If so, read only one byte at a time into the integer.

Comment: The number you gave, `86,183,936` in hex is: `0x05 0x23 0x10 0x00`.  Do those values make sense in the context of your file??  *(eg. 0, 16, 35, 5)*

Answer (score 1):

I tried running your program on a data file I created and it works fine. I suspect that your data file is not formatted correctly.

I am running on a little endian processor with 32 bit integers. This is the format of my binary file:
[image]